# How to set bracket indentation behavior in ST3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, indentation

Sublime Text has 3 ways to handle brackets indentation when I hit a new line button.

1.curly bracket

```
xxx = {
  |cursor|
}
```

2.parenthesis

```
xxx = (
  |cursor|)
```

3.square bracket

```
xxx = [
|cursor|]
```

How could I set all of them to behave like curly bracket

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Default keybindings, there is this:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

which provides the functionality for pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> between the `{` and `}` braces. The macro adds 2 newlines, moves the cursor to after the first one and reindents the line.

You can therefore achieve the same functionality between `(` and `)` and `[` and `]` by adding this to your user keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\[$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\]", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Hi. This helped me somewhat, but I still get different behaviour. With parantheses the closing one will be indented with the cursor and for square brackets the cursor isn't indented at all..

Comment: I guess this is due to the indentation rules ST is using in your case @ViggoV - which language/syntax are you experiencing this behavior with?

Comment: Javascript/ES6. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865347/smart-indenting-of-brackets-parenthesis-in-sublime-text-2, but it didn't do the trick.. I've reverted to vscode for the time being...

Comment: I had the "the closing paren will be indented with the cursor" problem as well. This answer plus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865347/smart-indenting-of-brackets-parenthesis-in-sublime-text-2#comment39926321_23672859 fixed it for me in all languages :) But yeah, square brackets are broken differently and I haven't found a fix for those.