# How do you set the return space on the parentheses in sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I type `action()` and hit return in the between the parentheses, I get this:

```
action (
    )
```

instead of this:

```
action (
)
```

How do I change this?

I have this in my keybindings right now but it only works in non-js files-

```
[
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\[$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\]", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["super+shift+\\"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar"},
    {"keys": ["tab"], "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", "context":
      [
        { "operand": "source.js", "operator": "equal", "match_all": true, "key": "selector" },
        { "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty" },
        { "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true, "key": "has_next_field" },
        { "operand": false, "operator": "equal", "match_all": true, "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "match_all": true, "key": "is_abbreviation" }
      ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bracket indentation behavior in ST3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456641/how-to-set-bracket-indentation-behavior-in-st3)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't fix it

Comment: It works in some file types but not js

Comment: Have you tried to set `"smart_indent": false,` in your user settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing is working out then you can write a snippet for yourself in sublime like this (Menu Bar -> Tools -> Developer -> New snippet) and put the following code and save it.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
action(${1:}
)
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>act</tabTrigger>
    <!-- <scope>source.JavaScript</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

It is a temporary solution not the best one. But for time being it can work.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it to work was, from within a *.js file in ST3, click `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific`. A separate window with 2 panes should open. In the right-hand pane add

```
"auto_indent": false,
```

between the braces and Save. When you go back into the JavaScript file and type `action()` and hit return in the between the parentheses there should be no more indenting.