# How can I expand round and square brackets, the way curly brackets are expanded in Sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In sublime when I type { and press enter the pair of curly brackets expand quite beautifully as follows, 
[image]

But when I try to expand ( and [ brackets, they don't expand that way. They expand in very weird way, and I have to press multiple keys to fix it. they expand as folows,

[image]

[image]

Is there some way to fix this behavior ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bracket indentation behavior in ST3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456641/how-to-set-bracket-indentation-behavior-in-st3)

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your Preference->Settings-User:

```
"indent_to_bracket": true
```

see if you like it