# How to set bracket indentation in sublime text to put the bracket on a new line with a tab?

Tags: sublimetext3

Using sublime text (3) I'd like to use this old fashioned kind of indentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style):

```
if (a > 1)
  {
  printf("yay");
  return;
  }
```

but all I get from the settings is this:

```
if (a > 1)
{
   printf("boo");
   return;
}
```

is there a way to have the bracket auto indented as in my first example? I'm somewhat ok with having to push tab once myself to indent, but sublime text insists on adding another indentation after that so that the brackets no longer line up with the start of the printf statement.

Comment: I found a [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html) about indention settings for sublime text and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456641/how-to-set-bracket-indentation-behavior-in-st3) about the bracket indention. Maybe this is helpful.

Comment: thanks but that documentation doesn't answer the question. After banging my head on this for a while I ended up switching to vscode which works pretty close to how I desire out of the box.